# Application is missing required files

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, sharpdevelop

Pic of Error: http://s23.postimg.org/7uj6qcxtn/9708083373e57a9ec91e4296e302f88e.png

> Cannot Download the Application. The Application is missing required Files. Contact Application Vendor For Assistance.

So I'm building a windows form application using SharpDevelop 5.2 and I'm trying to make a standalone/version someone else would be able to use on another machine. In sharpdevelop (and visual studio 2015RC) when debugging the program runs just fine and opens and everything works, no errors. However whenever I try to run it though the files in /bin/Debug/ or /bin/Release/ it doesn't work.

when i run the .exe nothing happens, no window no popup nothing, and when i run the .application file i get the error in the picture above and the details gives me this:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34209
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/Simbuild/Downloads/evix2/evix2/bin/Debug/Evix%20Charachter%20Creator.application
Application url         : file:///C:/Users/Simbuild/Downloads/evix2/evix2/bin/Debug/Evix%20Charachter%20Creator.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity     : Evix Charachter Creator.application, Version=0.0.1.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
Application Identity        : Evix Charachter Creator.exe, Version=0.0.1.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\Evix Charachter Creator.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading file:///C:/Users/Simbuild/Downloads/evix2/evix2/bin/Debug/compas.ico did not succeed.
    + Could not find file 'C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\compas.ico'.
    + Could not find file 'C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\compas.ico'.
    + Could not find file 'C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\compas.ico'.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
* The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
* The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [6/22/2015 12:36:59 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\Evix Charachter Creator.application has started.
* [6/22/2015 12:37:00 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [6/22/2015 12:37:00 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
* [6/22/2015 12:37:00 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
* [6/22/2015 12:37:02 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
* [6/22/2015 12:37:02 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [6/22/2015 12:37:03 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading file:///C:/Users/Simbuild/Downloads/evix2/evix2/bin/Debug/compas.ico did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.WebException
    - Could not find file 'C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\compas.ico'.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.WebException
    - Could not find file 'C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\compas.ico'.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
        at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException
    - Could not find file 'C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\compas.ico'.
    - Source: mscorlib
    - Stack trace:
        at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
        at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
        at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
        at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
        at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
        at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

My program is done in C# with windows forms and doesn't involve any online components or any urls to download or update it from, so all i'm trying to do is make a version anyone can run on a windows machine.

My machine is Windows 8.1

Comment: Did you mark `compas.ico` as content in the project?

Comment: Moving the compas.ico into the debug folder gets rid of this error but it still won't open, now there's a new error
`application validation did not succeed` under details the error is  ` ERROR SUMMARY
 Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
 * Activation of C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\Evix Charachter Creator.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
  + File, Evix Charachter Creator.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is looking for `compas.ico` inside the build directory, while it probably resides in some other directory in your project.

Comment: Moving the compas.ico into the debug folder gets rid of this error but it still won't open, now there's a new error 'application validation did not succeed' under details the error is ` ERROR SUMMARY Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log. * Activation of C:\Users\Simbuild\Downloads\evix2\evix2\bin\Debug\Evix Charachter Creator.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected: + File, Evix Charachter Creator.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.`